# How can i change value in TextField value from viewModel in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, textfield, android-jetpack-compose

I am using [jetpack-compose](/questions/tagged/jetpack-compose) in my project, and don't know how to change a `TextField`'s value from my ViewModel.

*In my Activity:*

```kotlin
...
@Composable
fun myView() {
    var dName = remember {
        mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(""))
    }
    TextField(
        value = dName.value, 
        onValueChange = { dName.value = it }, 
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )
}
...
```

*In my ViewModel:*

```kotlin
...
var dName = MutableStateFlow("")
...
```

I want to call `dName.value = "test"`  in my ViewModel and change the shown value in the `TextField`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 11):

You can also use `mutableStateOf` instead of `MutableStateFlow`. I think it much simple.

ViewModel

```
var dname by mutableStateOf("init value")
```

Composable

```
TextField(
    value = viewModel.dname,
    onValueChange = { viewModel.dname = it }
)
```

In `ViewModel`, when you want to change the value, you can call `dname = "test"`

Comment: out of interest, is this also acceptable in the viewmodel: `var textFieldValue by mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue())`?

Comment: Note that we don't use `remember` and viewModel.dname`.value`. You don't have to use `onValueChange` if you just print new value.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have a reference to your viewModel called `viewModel`, you just have to call `viewModel.name.collectAsState()`. But beyond that, I suggest keeping the data logic in the ViewModel, by making the MutableStateFlow private and exposing an immutable StateFlow and a setter method to the composable.

```kotlin
// ViewModel
private val _name = MutableStateFlow("")
val name = _name.asStateFlow()

fun setName(name: String) {
  _name.value = name
}
```

```kotlin
// Composable
val name = viewModel.name.collectAsState()
TextField(
  value = name,
  onValueChange = viewModel::setName
)
```

As you can see, I'm not using `remember { mutableStateOf(...) }` here, because the StateFlow in the ViewModel is the single source of truth.

Your approach of setting the composable's value imperatively doesn't make sense in the declarative API that Jetpack Compose provides.

Try reading up on declarative/imperative UI and state in Jetpack compose as well as kotlin flow to learn more.

Comment: Thanks，
According to your modification it runs very well

Comment: _name come from???  I don't your dialect of english.

Comment: From the official docs: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text#state-mgmt *Avoid using reactive streams like StateFlow to represent your TextField state, as these structures introduce asynchronous delays. Instead, use MutableState*

Comment: This is a rare occasion where an answer is 100% correct and with the best practices. This should be mark as a answer.